# Is AsyncTask delivering any response between onDestroy() and onCreate() callbacks of a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-orientation

I know I came a bit too late to the party and over the past 3 years (or maybe longer) there've been thousands and thousands of discussion like this one (unfortunately most of them involving activities and not fragments), but I'm curious about one thing.

Having the following piece of code, can `mFragment` be null when the AsyncTask's callback `onError()` or `onSuccess()` gets called after the screen orientation changes? So the AsyncTask starts, I rotate the screen of the device and at some point the AsyncTask will return an error or a success. When this happens, can the mFragment be null?

I already know that this cannot happen when dealing with Activities because basically no messages will be processed between a call to `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` of the previous instance and `onCreate()` of the new instance of the activity.
Unfortunately I couldn't find anything about this rule when it comes to fragments.

Do you guys know anything about this?

Thank you for your answers!

```
public class Fragment extends Fragment {
   private WorkerFragment mWorkerFragment;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      mWorkerFragment =(WorkerFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("worker_fragment");
      if (mWorkerFragment == null) {
         mWorkerFragment = new WorkerFragment();
         getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(mWorkerFragment, "worker_fragment").commit();
      }
      if (savedInstanceState == null) {
         mWorkerFragment.performAsyncTask();
      }

   private static class WorkerFragment extends Fragment {
      private TypeOfAsyncTask mAsyncTask;
      private Fragment mFragment;
      private Callback mCallback = new Callback() {

         @Override
         public void onError(Error error) {
            // Can mFragment be null here?
            mFragment.onSendRequestError(error);
         }

         @Override
         public void onSuccess(Result result) {
            // Can mFragment be null here?
            mFragment.onSendRequestSuccess(result);
         }
      };

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setRetainInstance(true);
      }

      @Override
      public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
         mFragment = (Fragment) getTargetFragment();
      }

      @Override
      public void onDetach() {
         super.onDetach();
         mFragment = null;
      }

      private void performAsyncTask() {
         mAsyncTask = new TypeOfAsyncTask(mCallback);
         mAsyncTask.execute();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about `onDestroy` and `onCreate` for Fragments. However, it is guaranteed that nothing else will be run on the main thread between `onAttach` and `onDetach` of a fragment. So you might consider using that instead of onCreate.